# Implications of leaving a system app in debug mode?

Tags: android, debugging, system, exploit

What are the possible dangers/implications of leaving a system app in debug mode, in a public OTA? Does it allow privilege escalation, by using something like run-as?
Thank you.

EDIT: A bit more clarification, if I leave a system app as a debug app, is it possible to use

run-as com.mydebug.app

to switch to a system UID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it's not possible. run-as doesn't switch to any lower UIDs than AID_APP.